# Can virtual terminals (ctrl+alt+f*) use external monitors?

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, virtual-console

My laptop has a broken screen (for a while now) and unfortunately I won't be able to fix/replace it for a little while longer than I hoped. Is there some way that I can get VT's to show on the external monitor? (I can't ssh into it, I don't have another computer to do that with).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, depending on the laptop. Anything that uses the standard VGA text mod shouldn't have a problem with an external monitor, although you may need to switch on the external monitor using the keyboard switch.
I had an HP laptop with a broken screen & was working with both the command line & X with an external monitor, without having the enable the screen when using a VT.

Comment: is there a way to force this from the VT?

Answer (score 1):

I had a laptop with a similar problem, and what I did was to press the key sequence to switch to the external monitor while it was going through the bios screens, before Linux or grub was involved.